# Top-navigation choices

Tags: script, tampermonkey, topbar, navigation

## Stack Exchange Top Nav Choices ( [install](https://github.com/makyen/StackExchange-userscripts/raw/master/Top-Nav-Choices/Stack_Exchange_Top_Nav_Choices.user.js) ) <sub><sup>( [GitHub](https://github.com/makyen/StackExchange-userscripts/tree/master/Top-Nav-Choices) )</sup></sub>

*Top Nav Choices* changes the new Stack Exchange/Stack Overflow top navigation based on the preferences you set. The preferences are accessed on your normal Stack Exchange preferences page<sup>1</sup>.

Default changed top navigation on Stack Overflow with dark theme, and inbox and achievements on the left and the help button added (all changes are options):
[image: Default changed top navigation on Stack Overflow]

Stack Overflow with stock light theme and different drop-down button placement:
[image: SO light theme different drop-down placement]

Default top navigation on Meta Stack Exchange:
[image: Default top navigation Meta Stack Exchange]

## Available options:

- Merge the Site Switcher with the site logo (on the left).
- Dark Top-Navigation theme on Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Overflow.
- Sticky Top-Navigation (all sites with new navigation).
- Adjust the top navigation height
- Add the help button if it's not already displayed.
- On Stack Overflow, show "Jobs" instead of "Developer Jobs".
- Apply the selected height to sites other than Stack Overflow/Meta Stack Overflow.
- Show the orange line along the top of the Top-Navigation on Stack Overflow/Meta Stack Overflow.
- Narrow the space taken by "Questions", etc. on Stack Overflow/Meta Stack Overflow.
- Change the position to left, right, or center for the drop-down menu buttons:

  - Inbox
  - Achievements
  - Reviews
  - Help
  - Site Switcher
  - Other (moderator tools?)
- Adjust the spacing used for the "center" drop-down position.

### Preferences example

[image: Preferences example]

### Additional features / bugs

Please, feel free to [open an issue](https://github.com/makyen/StackExchange-userscripts/issues/new) if you desire an additional feature. You should, of course, also do so if you encounter a bug. Alternately, you can report bugs and make feature requests as comments or answers to this question.

### Moderator tools

The "other" category should pick up the moderator tools. I'm not a moderator on any Stack Exchange site, so I'm unable to test it. I'm happy to update the script to have a explicit moderator tools drop-down button location selection. However, to do so I need either access to the top-nav HTML, or, at a minimum, the js-button `class` which is applied to the button (which should look like `js-[something]-button`) and the class applied to the drop-down (which should look something like `[same something]-dialog`). If they have that format, then I need to know the "something". If they don't have that format, I'm going to need the details. I also need to know if it's more than one drop-down button (appears to be so from screenshots). If the moderator tools are more than one drop down, I'm going to need the "something" for both.

## Getting the code

#### [Install](https://github.com/makyen/StackExchange-userscripts/raw/master/Top-Nav-Choices/Stack_Exchange_Top_Nav_Choices.user.js) from GitHub

This is a user-script, so you will need [Greasemonkey, Tampermonkey, or other user script manager](https://stackapps.com/tags/script/info).

#### The source code is on [GitHub](https://github.com/makyen/StackExchange-userscripts/tree/master/Top-Nav-Choices)

Please file any issues there

### Contact

You can contact me through Stack Exchange comments or chat. Alternately, through filing issues on GitHub.

### Compatibility notes

*Top Nav Choices* has been tested on Chrome (Tampermonkey) and Firefox (Greasemonkey). It should be compatible with other browsers and user script managers.

### License

Top Nav Choices' code is released under [CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), the international version of the license used for all contributions to Stack Exchange.

---

<sup>1. The URL for your preferences page is `https://[Stack Exchange site]/users/preferences/[your user #]`). You can get there by going to your profile page and selecting: <kbd>Edit Profile & Settings</kbd> (tab) ➞ <kbd>Preferences</kbd> (sidebar under "SITE SETTINGS").</sup> The added preferences will show up on all stack exchange sites (except Area 51, which doesn't have preferences).

Comment: feature request: click once and move over to the other button to drop *its* menu down, like it was working originally

Comment: also please add a setting to move the search input to the right of everything

Comment: The moderator diamond in the toolbar should [light up blue when the mod inbox receives a new message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDG9F.png) (e.g. due to a mod message or new question on meta) but [it doesn't light up when using this userscript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovVvc.png).

Comment: @Null, Thank you for reporting the issue. There was a general problem with the icons not changing color, which affected some of the icons. The most noticeable is the mod icon, because it doesn't also have a badge. That is resolved in the next version. Let me see if I actually get that version out quickly.

Comment: No rush to fix it. This is a nice userscript otherwise. Thanks!